# Center widget vertically inside a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview

I'm new to Flutter so I train myself by making a simple form. I realized while I was debugging on my iPhone the virtual keyboard triggered an error: `"A RenderFlex overflowed by 29 pixels on the bottom"`. I fixed this issue by wrapping my Container inside a `SingleChildScrollView`.

The problem now is my Column's content is no longer centered. I can't figure out why ...

Here's my code to help you to understand :

```
List<Widget> _buildBody() {
    var listWidget = List<Widget>();

    SingleChildScrollView singleChild = SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/github.png',
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _usernameController,
                        autofocus: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Username',
                            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle)))),
                Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Password', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key)),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text('Submit'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _handleSubmit();
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));

    listWidget.add(singleChild);

    if (_requesting) {
      var modal = new Stack(
        children: [
          new Opacity(
            opacity: 0.3,
            child: const ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ],
      );
      listWidget.add(modal);
    }

    return listWidget;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Github Login'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }
```

I added the property "mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center" to my Column. It worked well before I wrapped it into the SingleChildScrollView.

If someone could help me and explain me why it doesn't work anymore I would really appreciated it :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to vertically center a vertically scrollable content. Your scroll should be within the centered content, not on its parent

Comment: So I have to put my SingleChildScrollView inside Column’s children ? But where should I put all my containers ? @RémiRousselet

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Solution:**

Put your top level `Stack` inside `Center` widget.

```
body: Center(child: Stack(
      children: _buildBody(),
    )));
```

**Tip to debug:**

Use `Flutter Inspector` to find where the layout is going wrong.

I edited your code a bit(to make to work in my local) and then I inspected. It showed like below

[image]

We have a `Stack` and `SingleChildScrollView` as per code(refer to the right side of the diagram where the stack of widgets are displayed). As size is determined by `SingleChildScrollView`(contents inside it), `Stack` occupies only a little space and by default, it aligned at `top`. So put it under `Center`, the whole Stack view will come in the center.

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm ! I was focus on the Column's behaviour I didn't think about Center the whole Stack ...

Answer (score 182):

[ArtiomLK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5212904/artiomlk) Suggested a solution in comments which helped me:

wrap `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Center`. The widgets tree is:

`Center( child: SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(...)))`

None of the others helped.

Comment: this was the fix for me as well!

Comment: Yes this helped!
In case it throws an "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" exception and your widget tree looks like this: Center > Expanded > SingleChildScrollView. Just delete the Expanded widget and you are good to go!

Comment: @Carlit0 you can also wrap SingleChildScrollView. with SizedBox     instade of Deleting                  ------------------------------------->         Center > Expanded > SizedBox>SingleChildScrollView<----------

Comment: earlier for me it was a good fix but it forces the list to center and space is left on the top if there is not enough list items .

Answer (score 22):

You can use "Center" widget like as

return Center(
child: SingleChildScrollView()
)

Answer (score 20):

use LayoutBuilder widget to wrap all the widget and use Spacer widget before and after your centered widget inside the Column

```
    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.maxWidth, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Spacer(),
                          Container(
                             child: //your widget
                          ),
                          Spacer()
                        ]
                    ),
                  )
              )
          );
        })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great. I had to remove the IntrinsicHeight to prevent an overflow, but it still worked fine. When the keyboard appears things scroll nicely.

Answer (score 16):

There's a section about it in the official docs:

> Using SingleChildScrollView with a Column

*Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html*

However I found that using a combination of the above worked better. Namely confining the `Column` to the minimum size possible (`MainAxisSize.min`). This should be fine, as the `SingleChildScrollView` will take up as much space as is possible on screen, before scrolling can happen.

```
Widget _buildPortraitPage() {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // <-- notice 'min' here. Important
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/my-image.png'),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Text('My content'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The layout engine in Flutter is pretty hard to figure out.

Comment: I was doing SingleChildScrollView -> Center. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

wrap **SingleChildScrollView** with **center**

```
child: Center(
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
```

[image: center in SingleChildScrollView]

Answer (score 6):

Just wrap the `Column` in a `Center`. I used that for my apps and it seems to center the contents of my `Column` even inside a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work for my case :/

Comment: It did work on my case, but I wrapped the `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Center`. The widgets tree is: ```Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(...```

Comment: I was searching a fix for this for a long time, this is the only way it worked for me. Thanks @ArtiomLK !

Answer (score 6):

There's another way to achieve this:

```
Center(
    child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: []
    )

)
```

Comment: the advantage of this versus the other methods is that the scrollbar is shown on the edge of the screen, as it should be, and not at the edge of the content, which might not be on the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

use `SingleChildScrollView` widget

```
body: Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your SingleChildScrollView(), with center. and here you go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SingleChildScrollView -> ConstrainedBox(with min height and width) -> Center

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget centerScrollView(Widget childWidget) {
  return Center(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: childWidget));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CustomScrollView` and `SliverFillRemaining`  instead of using `SingleChildScrollView`.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Center(
          child: new Text('ABC')
        ),
      ),
    ]
  )
);
```